# Check if XML has two different types of element node how to bring it in output XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I already have an input XML

```
<tutorial>
<lessons>
<lesson>
     chapter1 unit 1 page1
</lesson>
<lesson>
     unit 1 
</lesson>
</lessons>
</tutorial>
```

The output should be

```
<Geography>
<historical>
    <social>
       <toc1>
     <toc>
      <chapter>
    chapter1
      <chapter>
      <unit>
    unit 1
      </unit>
      <pages>
    page1
      </pages>
      </toc>
       </toc1>
    <social>
</historical>
```

actually i am getting confused here

```
 <lesson>
chapter1 unit 1 page1
</lesson>
<lesson>
 unit 1 
</lesson>
```

here i need two outpus

for the first lesson i need it as above output

for the second lesson i need it as output like below

```
 <historical>
    <social>
       <toc1>
  <toc>
      <unit>
    unit 1
      </unit>   
  <toc>
       </toc1>
    <social>
</historical>
```

but sometimes i will get both type in xml i am totally confused how to do this.

can any one guide me here it can be in both XSLT1.0 and XSLT2.0

Regards
Karthic

Comment: You're right: you are confused. Your readers will be equally confused. We can't help you write code unless you can express the requirements clearly. Giving an input and an output document is sometimes enough to enable people to work out the transformation rules; that's not the case here. We need a much more thorough explanation of what possible inputs there are and how each possible input should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="'chapter', 'unit', 'pages'"/>

 <xsl:template match="lessons">
    <Geography>
      <historical>
        <social>
           <toc1>
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
           </toc1>
        </social>
      </historical>
    </Geography>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lesson[matches(., '(chapter\s*\d+)?\s+(unit\s*\d+)\s+(page\s*\d+)?')]">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="."
   regex="(chapter\s*\d+)?\s+(unit\s*\d+)\s+(page\s*\d+)?">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <toc>
         <xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
          <xsl:if test="regex-group(current())">
           <xsl:element name="{$vNames[current()]}">
                <xsl:sequence select="regex-group(current())"/>
           </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </toc>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<tutorial>
    <lessons>
    <lesson>
         chapter1 unit 1 page1
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
         unit 1
    </lesson>
    </lessons>
</tutorial>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Geography>
  <historical>
    <social>
      <toc1>
        <toc>
          <chapter>chapter1</chapter>
          <unit>unit 1</unit>
          <pages>page1</pages>
        </toc>
        <toc>
          <unit>unit 1</unit>
        </toc>
      </toc1>
    </social>
  </historical>
</Geography>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of XSLT 2.0 Regular expression capabilities such as:

1. The **[`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-analyze-string)** and **[`<xsl:matching-substring>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-matching-substring)** instrunctions.
2. The **[`regex-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#regex-group)** function.

Comment: Hi @Dimitre I am out of station Once i back i will check thank you

Comment: @karthic: No problem, do have a look at the answer when convenient.

Comment: Hi @Dimitre I have one more query is that possible can i modify in this question or can i create new question please guide me.

Comment: @karthic: It is good practice not to wind a question over time -- Please, ask a new question. I would be glad to answer your next questions. This answer fully solves the problem as defined in your current question -- please, consider accepting it.

Comment: I have posted little brief about this question please look that and guide me thanks in advance

Comment: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499010/check-condition-in-xslt#comment15192586_11499010'>Link</a>

Comment: Hi @ Dimitre Could you able to saw that question which i given the link above

Comment: Thank you very much @Dimitre  i have one more query in that link