# check condition in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Below is the input XML (Little Big) sorry for the bigger input XML and as well as output xml

```
<tutorial>
<lessons>
   <lesson>
     chapter unit 1 page
</lesson>
    <lesson>
        chapter unit 10~ page
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        chapter unit page
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        note lesson
    </lesson>
 <lessons1>
    <lesson>
        chapter unit 1 page
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        description page
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        chapter unit page
    </lesson>
</lessons1>
</lessons>
</tutorial>
```

Below is my Output Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Geography>


 <historical>
  <social>
     <toc1>
        <toc>
           <chapter>chapter</chapter>
           <unit>unit 1</unit>
           <pages>page</pages>
        </toc>
         <toc>
           <chapter>chapter</chapter>
           <unit>unit 10</unit>
           <pages>page</pages>
        </toc>
         <toc>
           <chapter>chapter</chapter>
           <unit>unit 10</unit>
           <pages>page</pages>
        </toc>
        <toc>
          <sample>
           <original>Note Lesson</orginal>
          </sample>
        </toc>
     </toc1>
     <toc2>
        <toc>
           <chapter>chapter</chapter>
           <unit>unit 1</unit>
           <pages>page</pages>
        </toc>
        <toc>
          <sample>
           <original>description page</orginal>
          </sample>
        </toc>
         <toc>
           <chapter>chapter</chapter>
           <unit>unit 10</unit>
           <pages>page</pages>
        </toc>
     </toc2>
  </social>
```

It's quiet big output XML file sorry for that.

In unit if i have unit 1 in output it will displayed as unit 1 but for example if i have unit10~ it will displayed as unit 10 the ~ has to removed if there is no value in by default it has to displayed unit 10.

Little Brief Explanation

My Output XML has to differentiate in three categories

1) Chapter

2) unit

3) pages

The input will be in three different types of formats

1) The XML have Chapter,unit(number with tilda symbol) & pages

2) The XML have Chapter,unit(number without tilda symbol) & pages

3) The XML have only pages ex..(note & description) so here if for example i have 10~(unit) the output will show 10, if the input xml doesn't have the value (for unit) in output xml it will show 10 as default number – karthic yesterday

Please help me and guide me with the help of XSLT.

Regards
Karthic

Comment: Your XML input sample is not well-formed, as it is missing the closing elements for **lessons** and **tutorial**. Also, could you explain a bit more how the transformation works. It is not clear where the elements **historical**, **social** and **toc** come from as they do not appear in the input sample at all. Thanks!

Comment: hi Tim Now i updated the input xml for as you said.Historical, Social & TOC it has to create dynamically using XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="'chapter', 'unit', 'pages'"/>

     <xsl:template match="lessons">
        <Geography>
          <historical>
            <social>
               <toc1>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="lesson"/>
               </toc1>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="lessons1"/>
            </social>
          </historical>
        </Geography>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="lesson[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'chapter')]">
      <xsl:variable name="vNorm" select=
                     "translate(normalize-space(), '~', '')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vAtNumber" select=
                     "substring-after($vNorm, 'chapter unit')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vNum" select=
       "if(matches($vAtNumber, '^\s*\d+'))
          then replace($vAtNumber, '(^\s*(\d+)).*$', '$2')
          else '10'
       "/>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="."
       regex="(chapter\s+)(unit\s*)(((\d*~?)\s+)?page)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <toc>
             <chapter>chapter</chapter>
             <unit>unit <xsl:value-of select="$vNum"/></unit>
             <pages>page</pages>
          </toc>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="lesson">
       <sample>
         <original><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></original>
       </sample>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="lessons1">
      <toc2>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </toc2>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<tutorial>
    <lessons>
       <lesson>
         chapter unit 1 page
    </lesson>
        <lesson>
            chapter unit 10~ page
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            chapter unit page
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            note lesson
        </lesson>
     <lessons1>
        <lesson>
            chapter unit 1 page
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            description page
        </lesson>
        <lesson>
            chapter unit page
        </lesson>
    </lessons1>
    </lessons>
</tutorial>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Geography>
   <historical>
      <social>
         <toc1>
            <toc>
               <chapter>chapter</chapter>
               <unit>unit 1</unit>
               <pages>page</pages>
            </toc>
            <toc>
               <chapter>chapter</chapter>
               <unit>unit 10</unit>
               <pages>page</pages>
            </toc>
            <toc>
               <chapter>chapter</chapter>
               <unit>unit 10</unit>
               <pages>page</pages>
            </toc>
            <sample>
               <original>note lesson</original>
            </sample>
         </toc1>
         <toc2>
            <toc>
               <chapter>chapter</chapter>
               <unit>unit 1</unit>
               <pages>page</pages>
            </toc>
            <sample>
               <original>description page</original>
            </sample>
            <toc>
               <chapter>chapter</chapter>
               <unit>unit 10</unit>
               <pages>page</pages>
            </toc>
         </toc2>
      </social>
   </historical>
</Geography>
```

Comment: hi @Dimitre thanks for the output this working fine but if i want to add one more lesson i need to add in xslt ? 

please guide me

Comment: Hi @Dimitre is that possible to do dynamic for this please guide me

Comment: @karthic: The current question is completely answered. Please ask a new question. Please, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the "~", use translate(xxx, '~', '')

Beyond that, I'm afraid you're not making your requirements clear. For example, I don't understand this clause:

if there is no value in by default it has to displayed unit 10

Comment: hi Michael, right now i want my input XML has to differentiate in three categories 1) Chapter 2) unit and 3) pages

The input will be in three different types of formats

1)  The XML have Chapter,unit(number with tilda symbol) & pages

2)  The XML have Chapter,unit(number without tilda symbol) & pages

3)  The XML have only pages ex..(note & description)

so here if for example i have 10~(unit) the output will show 10,  if the input xml doesn't have the value (for unit) in output xml it will show 10 as default number

Comment: Hi guys please help me how to bring the input XML as output XML 

thanks in advance